# How to Delete a Wireless Hidden Network (Created by Me Previously as an ad-hoc Connection) in Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

I'm using Windows 10 Pro and I created an Ad-Hoc wireless connection to create a network equivalent to the previous "Ad-Hoc connection" in Windows 7 for sharing data between two laptops within the house.

This connection shows on the list of "Available Networks" as a "Hidden Network" and I cannot delete this "Hidden Network" now, having tried the following but "Hidden Network" still shows in the list of Available Networks:

- Chosen to "Forget" this connection from "Manage Known Networks"
- Deleted the "Hidden Adapters" from the Device Manager
- Restored the system from a previous image made by Macrium Reflect
- Deleted a registry entry from `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles`

How can I delete this "Hidden Network"?

Comment: "Hidden Network" could be referring to a nearby network with it's SSID obscured and does not refer to the Ad-Hoc network you created unless that Ad-Hoc network is still being broadcast.

Comment: I am  unable to find the "delete" or "remove network" option in Windows 10 (in Windows 7 there is the "remove network" option). Since I created this wireless connection I was never able to connect to it myself. When I tried to delete it,the only option I found was "forget". I have searched under cmd "netsh wlan show profiles" & deleted all the possible "offenders". How do I find out whether it is still broadcasting?

Comment: I'm not sure how to determine if it's still broadcasting, as I've never created an Ad-Hoc connection before since it's usually more efficient to go through a router.  Since you restored the system from a prior backup, it's more likely than not that the "Hidden Network" is referring to a nearby neighbor's or business' network which has it's SSID obscurred, something you should be able to determine by using WireShark and checking the MAC of that network against the output of: `ipconfig /all | findstr Physical` on both laptops

Comment: Thank you. That's a very helpful point. I will give it a crack at WireShark (never used it before though I have it with PacketTracer,which I use a lot for ccna).